# How to rewrite MVC 5 routes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have two question about generating routes in MVC 5.

---

This is example:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "ActionSite",
        url: "{userName}/sites/{action}/{localSiteName}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Site" }
);
```

`@Url.RouteUrl("ActionSite", new {  action="Edit", siteOrder = site.Order, localSiteName = site.LocalName, userName = ViewBag.UserName })`

generates the next url:
`https://localhost:44344/TestUser/sites/Edit/Site2?siteOrder=1`

---

1)How to hide variables? I want to hide: `?siteOrder=1`

2)`TestUser` is `userName`. At this moment I set manually it in all `[Authorize]` actions. Can I do this one time in some special method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About first question, RouteUrl assumes you are going to use the URL in a GET method and when you are using GET verb you have to append query string to the URL. siteOrder has to be in query because you did not put it into URL template. Any extra parameter goes into query string.

Solution here is to use POST instead of GET. Down side would be losing simple GET calls ( anchor) from client side. You have to use @Html.BeginForm instead of @Html.ActionLink.

Second question is not clear, if you generate URL like https://localhost:44344/TestUser/sites/Edit/Site2?siteOrder=1 then you will get username form URL.
for example:

```
public ActionResult Edit(string userName, string localSiteName){ }
```

username here will be "TestUser" and you have to check authentication if userName is same as User.Identity.GetUserName()
Or you can write AuthenticationFilter to do the authentication job for you.

But if you mean a way that Url.RouteUrl automatically fill in userName property based on User.Identity I think answer is no. You have to retrieve username somewhere in ActionFilters or in Action or if you are using ASP.Identity then you already have the user name all the way down to the View, just you need to call

```
@User.Identity.GetUserName()
```

in your View or Controller to get it.